# Appropriate Regex for this source using vb.net?

Tags: regex, vb.net

Help out a newbie here. I am trying to check duplicate content from forum posts. So far I have downloaded the source with webclient and tried Regex as well as mshtml without any luck. I am getting the lines with mshtml but not in the way I wanted, means I am not being able to seperate the individual comments. The source I am trying to read goes below :

```
<p>
    Hey Alton!</p>
<p>
    I am facing this problem also but i have search on the internet for the solution. There are few things that we need to do to solve this problem.</p>
<p>
    First of all make sure that you have latest drivers for you Graphics Card.</p>
```

The Codes I have tried so far

Regex:

```
    Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<p> .* </p>")
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(result)
    For Each itemcode As Match In matches
        ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.ToString)
    Next
```

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are trying to do a little better. Are you trying to compare content within `p` tags?

Comment: The [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) is a must for what you are trying to do

Comment: Do you know that the most upvoted answer on this site explains why is really a bad idea to use regex to parse html? [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @ ianbarker the source I have posted is a part of a comment which is inside a <div>. It goes like this : <div class="content KonaBody" >
  <div >
<!--INFOLINKS_ON-->
<!--paging_filter--><p>
 </p>
<p>
 .... </p>
<p>
 .... </p>
<p>
 .... </p>

<!--INFOLINKS_OFF-->
</div> I am trying to get the lines between <p> </p> in each division. There are 4 comments means, there are 4 <div> containing the data inside <p> tag. I am trying to use the regex to get all the comments and store them in a list box. @ Oded I downloaded and tried to use HTML Agility Pack but couldn't find any helpful tutorials.

Comment: @ Steve I read the thread but no way out for me.

Comment: Post a link to the page, and explain what you want to do. I mean after you have receieved the content of all the p tags, then what?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim regexObj As New Regex("<p>(.+?)</p>", RegexOptions.Singleline)
Dim matchResults As Match = regexObj.Match(subjectString)
While matchResults.Success

matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch()
End While
```